# Get service version at runtime

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

How to get the executing Service Fabric services (and application) versions at run time? I have tried the context, but both `StatefulServiceContext` and `StatelessServiceContext` do not provide that information.

Comment: Do you want to get a list of all Services/Applications deployed to ASF or just the Service/Application your current code is executing within?

Comment: Within the current one. The answers below sum it up. For application must query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `FabricClient` to get this information.

For the application version:

```
var applicationName = new Uri("fabric:/MyApp"); // or use Context.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationName
using (var client = new FabricClient())
{
    var applications = await client.QueryManager.GetApplicationListAsync(applicationName).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var version = applications[0].ApplicationTypeVersion;
}
```

For service versions -

From within a service class:

```
Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetServiceManifestVersion()
```

Or:

```
var serviceName = new Uri("fabric:/MyApp/MyService"); // or use Context.ServiceName
using (var client = new FabricClient())
{
    var services = await client.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(applicationName, serviceName).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var version = services[0].ServiceManifestVersion;
}
```

Notes:

- During an upgrade, you will get the old versions using this API. If you need the new version, use `FabricClient.ApplicationManager.GetApplicationUpgradeProgressAsync` and retrive the `TargetApplicationTypeVersion`
- You may want to cache `FabricClient` if you use it often (see [remarks here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.fabricclient.aspx#Anchor_7))
- The `CodePackageActivationContext` also contains the `CodePackageVersion`, which is different than the version of the service manifest

Comment: `ServiceManifestVersion` vs `CodePackageVersion` is a good point. So for the service version, why not to go after `Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetServiceManifestVersion()`?

Comment: @EliArbel "You may want to cache the `FabricClient`" - Is the client expensive to create?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use PowerShell.  To get the application type version:

```
Get-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName fabric:/MyApplication | Select -expand ApplicationTypeVersion
```

To get the service manifest version:

```
Get-ServiceFabricService -ApplicationName fabric:/MyApplication -ServiceName fabric:/MyApplication/MyStatefulService | Select -expand ServiceManifestVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but what about `this.Context.CodePackageActivationContext.CodePackageVersion`?

Comment: Is that an application version or a service version?

Comment: That's the service version.

Comment: What would be equivalent for the application? Considering that application is credited separately from its services, there's got to be something.

Comment: I've posted how to discover an application version, though it feels hacky that a service under SF application cannot retrieve application version w/o querying the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

To find out an application version:

```
var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
var applicationTypeList = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetApplicationTypeListAsync(
                             Context.CodePackageActivationContext.ApplicationTypeName);
var applicationType = applicationTypeList.FirstOrDefault();
var applicationVersion = applicationType?.ApplicationTypeVersion;
```